# How to grab the quoted strings from HTML headers?

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

Given this HTML snippet, how do I use python packages requests or xlml to find the quoted strings after href=?

```
<dl>
    <dt><a href="oq-phys.htm">
        <b>Physics and Astronomy</b></a>
    <dt><a href="oq-math.htm">
        <b>Mathematics</b></a>
    <dt><a href="oq-life.htm">
        <b>Life Sciences</b></a>
    <dt><a href="oq-tech.htm">
        <b>Technology</b></a>
    <dt><a href="oq-geo.htm">
        <b>Earth and Environmental Science</b></a>
</dl>
```

Comment: The snippet is from the following python code: 
    page = requests.get('http://www.openquestions.com')
    print (page.text)

Comment: You are confusing me by asking about requests and xml as if they were similar things. Do you want to get the content of a html page or do you want to parse the content and find specific parts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> to find the quoted strings after `href=`

Short `requests` + `beautifulsoup` solution:

```
import requests, bs4

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(requests.get('http://.openquestions.com').content, 'html.parser')
hrefs = [a['href'] for a in soup.select('dl dt a')]
print(hrefs)
```

The output:

```
['oq-phys.htm', 'oq-math.htm', 'oq-life.htm', 'oq-tech.htm', 'oq-geo.htm', 'oq-map.htm', 'oq-about.htm', 'oq-howto.htm', 'oqc/oqc-home.htm', 'oq-indx.htm', 'oq-news.htm', 'oq-best.htm', 'oq-gloss.htm', 'oq-quote.htm', 'oq-new.htm']
```

Answer (score 0):

For the above example , assuming we have html_string containing the above snippet.

```
import requests
import lxml.etree as LH
html_string =  LH.fromstring(requests.get('http://openquestions.com').text)
```

`for quoted_link in html_string.xpath('//a'):
   print(quoted_link.attrib['href'], quoted_link.text_content())`

Comment: I probably left out some vital information in the question, but the result was an error.   Thanks for your effort!

Answer (score 0):

There's going to be a lot of ways to skin this cat.  Here's a `requests`/`lxml` solution that doesn't include an (explicit) `for` loop:

```
import requests
from lxml.html import fromstring

req = requests.get('http://www.openquestions.com')
resp = fromstring(req.content)
hrefs = resp.xpath('//dt/a/@href') 
print(hrefs)
```

**Edit**

Why I wrote it like this:

- I prefer XPath to CSS selectors
- It's fast

Benchmark:

```
import requests,bs4
from lxml.html import fromstring
import timeit

req = requests.get('http://www.openquestions.com').content

def myfunc() :
    resp = fromstring(req)
    hrefs = resp.xpath('//dl/dt/a/@href')

print("Time for lxml: ", timeit.timeit(myfunc, number=100))

##############################################################

resp2 = requests.get('http://www.openquestions.com').content

def func2() :
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(resp2, 'html.parser')
    hrefs = [a['href'] for a in soup.select('dl dt a')]

print("Time for beautiful soup:", timeit.timeit(func2, number=100))
```

Output:

```
('Time for lxml: ', 0.09621267095780464)
('Time for beautiful soup:', 0.8594218329542824)
```